# TypeError: 'Arguments', 'callee' and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, applepay

I am trying to make a payment request while passing all required fields, but it throws a type error. I want to create a session that return a validateURL that i have to send to server to create a applepay session.

```js
getPaymentRequest = () => {
    const applePayMethod = {
      supportedMethods: 'https://apple.com/apple-pay',
      data: {
        version: 3,
        merchantIdentifier: 'my_verified_merchant_identifier',
        merchantCapabilities: ['supports3DS', 'supportsCredit', 'supportsDebit'],
        supportedNetworks: ['amex', 'discover', 'masterCard', 'visa'],
        countryCode: 'US'
      }
    }
    const paymentDetails = {
      total: {
        label: 'My Merchant',
        amount: { value: '27.50', currency: 'USD' }
      },
      displayItems: [{
        label: 'Tax',
        amount: { value: '2.50', currency: 'USD' }
      }, {
        label: 'Ground Shipping',
        amount: { value: '5.00', currency: 'USD' }
      }],
      shippingOptions: [{
        id: 'ground',
        label: 'Ground Shipping',
        amount: { value: '5.00', currency: 'USD' },
        selected: true
      }, {
        id: 'express',
        label: 'Express Shipping',
        amount: { value: '10.00', currency: 'USD' }
      }]
    }
    const debitModifier = {
      supportedMethods: 'https://apple.com/apple-pay',
      data: { paymentMethodType: 'debit' },
      total: {
        label: 'My Merchant',
        amount: { value: '26.50', currency: 'USD' }
      },
      additionalDisplayItems: [{
        label: 'Debit Card Discount',
        amount: { value: '-1.00', currency: 'USD' }
      }]
    }
    const paymentOptions = {
      requestPayerName: true,
      requestPayerEmail: true,
      requestPayerPhone: true,
      requestShipping: true,
      shippingType: 'shipping'
    }
    return {
      applePayMethod,
      paymentDetails,
      debitModifier,
      paymentOptions
    }
  }
  
  if (!window.PaymentRequest) {
      console.log('==========> payment reuqest not found ======>', window.PaymentRequest)
      return
    }
    const { applePayMethod, paymentDetails, paymentOptions } = this.getPaymentRequest()
    console.log('==========> get payment request details ======>', this.getPaymentRequest())
    try {
      const request = new PaymentRequest([applePayMethod], paymentDetails, paymentOptions)
      console.log('==========> getting request =========>', request)
    }
```

While creating Apple Pay session i am getting this type error. I am getting canMakePyaments 'true' but when i create a session it shows me error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Xhl.png)

```js
try {
      if(window.ApplePaySession.canMakePayments('my_verfied_merchant_identifier')){
          document.querySelector('apple-pay-button').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            const session = new window.ApplePaySession(3, {
              merchantIdentifier: 'my_verified_merchant_identifier',
              countryCode: 'US',
              currencyCode: 'USD',
              supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'masterCard', 'amex', 'discover'],
              merchantCapabilities: ['supports3DS'],
              total: { label: 'Your Merchant Name', amount: '10.00' },
            })
            session.onvalidatemerchant = (event) => {
              const validationURL = event.validationURL
              // after that i have to call my server for session
            }
          })
        }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('===============> error in catch block', e)
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's supposed to happen? How is the code you have posted relevant? It doesn't even use `arguments`.

Comment: The code shown won't cause the error you've mentioned, unless the error is inside the code of one of the methods being called that you haven't shown the code for.

Comment: @VLAZ, I read apple documentation, here is the reference, please have a look [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778021-onvalidatemerchant)

Comment: @Vishawjeet-124 the documentation does not include `arguments`. I still don't know what your code has to do with the problem you get. Nor how you manage to get the problem at all.

Comment: @VLAZ ,T.J. Crowder
please have a look now.
[reference](https://webkit.org/blog/8182/introducing-the-payment-request-api-for-apple-pay/)

Comment: There is still no code that will cause the issue. `arguments` is never used thus neither is `arguments.caller` or `argument.callee`. I still don't see why you would get an error.

Comment: @VLAZ  I dont know the issue correctly but did you see the last console that is same as in image. So, i think i am passing wrong or something diffrent while creating a payment request.

Comment: @VLAZ, T.J.Crowder, did you find something use-full that will help me to integrate apple pay.